# pushing variables into a secondary child object in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add variables to existing JSON data received from an API when a user hits add button. When i try i get this error.

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
```

The data is assigned to a variable called `pageList`
Below is how the data is returned from the server

DATA

```
[{"id":5,"referenceId":1189,"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Daniels","orders":[{"id":109,"meals":[{"id":47,"name":"Fried Rice","description":"This is a  very sweet meal","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":-20,"status":"ENABLED"}],"serveDate":"2019-07-11 00:00:00"}]}]
```

FUNCTION

```
AddtoList() {
       const meals =  {'id': '0','name': 'New Food', 'unitPrice':'5'}
       this.pageList.push({
                  'firstName': 'Jackson',
                  'lastName': 'Jack',
                  orders: {meals: meals}
                })
}
```

Comment: why are you creating orders as an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `orders` should be an array. Please see as below:

```
this.pageList.push({
  'firstName': 'Jackson',
   'lastName': 'Jack',
   orders: [{meals: meals}]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Update orders object to an array.

```
AddtoList() {
       const meals =  {'id': '0','name': 'New Food', 'unitPrice':'5'}
       this.pageList.push({
         'firstName': 'Jackson',
         'lastName': 'Jack',
         orders: [{meals: meals}]
        })
}
```